# Pattern recognizing

Tags: python, pattern-recognition

With an IQ of 70, I'm simply not smart enough to find out how I should do this.
But! What I want is... to let Python e.g. read a table from MySQL and find a pattern for columns!
Like, column X usually is value 'foo' when column Y is around '1.56' AND colum Z is around '756' e.g.
That it finds all this **'OBVIOUS'** data...
Do some of you have a simple plan for how I can do this? Or reference me to some information, book etc.? Not a book for a genius!

And, is Python suitable for this? It will contains around 600 000 rows, around 20 columns... and it's on a up today standard gaming computer.....

Comment: Pattern recognition is a fundamentally human task. But you can do **statistical analysis** on the data.

Comment: What you are looking for is [data mining](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_mining).  And its a complex business.

Comment: That's probably one of the most complicated algorithm requests that I've seen on stack overflow. Also, starting a question by posting your IQ is never a good start.

Comment: Don't feel bad. With an IQ of 70, you're probably still smarter than my gravitar.

Comment: Please remove the useless and uninformative "With an IQ of 70, I'm simply not smart enough to find out how I should do this".  It doesn't help us answer the question at all.

Answer (score 0):

This is a complex topic.  If you want to get started, try clustering your data using the [scipy clustering libraries](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/cluster.html).